# How to get form field names and values in Python?

Tags: python

I have a problem in web page, developed in python.

I have several fields (checkbox, textarea, etc) in form, and each field has some unique names.

I can save the value of known fields

i.e.

```
field_name = 'fl_textarea'    
field_value = form.getvalue(field_name)
```

But how I can get the value of unknown field names ? I also need to save field names into the variable.

When I have printed the contents of submitted form

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print "<p>"+ str(form) +"</p>"
```

It looks like this:

```
FieldStorage(None, None, MiniFieldStorage('flatt2695', 'abc-xyz'), MiniFieldStorage('flatt2696', 'abc-123xyz'), MiniFieldStorage('flatt2697', 'onoff'), ...
```

So, how I can get these field names and values one by one into the variables ?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: No framework, its simple python code to develop a webpage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

its good you have explained everything in precise way.

Since you already have FieldStorage, so its easy for me to answer ;-)

If you want to get name of the form fields then print `form.keys()`.

Other part is bit tricky. You can loop through the form.key() and write your own logic to retrieve the values on the base of keys.

I wrote a piece of compiled code here, but you can customize it according to your need.

```
variable = ""
value = ""
r = ""
for key in form.keys():
        variable = str(key)
        value = str(form.getvalue(variable))
        r += "<p>"+ variable +", "+ value +"</p>\n" 

fields = "<p>"+ str(r) +"</p>"
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks very much,

It solved my problem. 

Cheers :)