# http.server - Unsupported method ('POST')

Tags: php, python-3.x, http, webserver

So I have created a website, when the user tries to fill out the login form (username and password), the following error message is displayed:

```
Error response
Error code: 501

Message: Unsupported method ('POST').

Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED - Server does not support this operation.
```

For the server im using Python 3 [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html). To start the server i have a batch file containing the following code:

```
python -m http.server 80
```

I'm looking for a way to receive the login credentials the user submitted, and store them in a text file (.txt).

After doing some research I got the impression I need to create a PHP script, i have no idea how to do this. here is my attempt at it:

```
<?php
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);

echo $username, ' ', $password;
?>
```

Comment: `501` is a response from the Python server so it needs to be configured to accept the POST data method. PHP is completely irrelevant at this time.

Comment: How would I configure the server to accept POST?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using Python server? There are several mature servers to choose from.

Comment: Any Server will do, as long as it can accept a post request and write the data to a text file. And is standalone executable, i don't to install anything, server just be portable.

Comment: See my answer, but if the server does not matter then have a look at [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). There is also XAMMP, MAMP, LAMP depending on your operating system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you @MonkeyZeus, I managed to solve the problem by making a few changes to your code.

```
import socketserver
import http.server
import logging
import cgi

PORT = 80

class ServerHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        logging.error(self.headers)
        http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

    def do_POST(self):
        logging.error(self.headers)
        form = cgi.FieldStorage(
            fp=self.rfile,
            headers=self.headers,
            environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                     'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
                     })
        for item in form.list:
            logging.error(item)
        http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

        with open("data.txt", "w") as file:
            for key in form.keys(): 
                file.write(str(form.getvalue(str(key))) + ",")

Handler = ServerHandler

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

When the post request is received, a text file called "data" is created. A for loop is then used to iterate through the keys ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861824/how-to-get-form-field-names-and-values-in-python)) and write there values to the file.

Comment: Very nice, I'm glad my answer helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and used it by using the following command to run the server: php -S localhost:[insert port number here]